# How to fill a cell on a picture

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

My image contains a grid with different cells size. For an example I show you a similar image.

[image]

As you can see the cells don't have the same size. I have to fill the cell with any color when I'm clicking on it. How it's possible to detect a cell on an image like PhotoShop with the Paint Bucket tool ? Should I use HTML5 canvas ?

I have to store all colored cell into my database and re-fill them for the next time. So I have to initialize a variable for each colored cell.

Do you have a code snippet to help me ?

Comment: SO get the coordinates of the click on the canvas, determine the section, and fill it in.

Comment: Google "flood fill in html canvas". That's what you need.